# How to remove KeyError with if else conditioning in python

Tags: python-2.7

If there is a character that is not in my key list, such as "X", how do I avoid it and continue without doing nothing to it? I am getting KeyError 'X' , cause there is a X in my sequence that I am looking at.

```
        keys = ["A", "C", "D", "E"]

        for char in keys:
            counts[char] = 0

        for line in gpcr: 
            if line.startswith(">"):
                line = line.replace(' ','')
                header = line.split()
                number = header[0].split('|')

                print "Id:",number[2]

                continue
                fo.write(number[2])
                fo.write('\n')              
            for char in line.strip(): 
                if char 
                counts[char] += 1               
            total = float(sum(counts.values()))

        toReturn = ''


        for key in keys:
            aa_per = (counts[key]/total)*100
            toReturn = toReturn + '%.2f'%aa_per + '%'+ '\t'
        fo.write(number[1])


        fo.write('\n')
        fo.write(''.join(str(x) for x in toReturn))
        fo.write('\n')

        print toReturn
fo.close()
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question so we can understand it.

Comment: Change your code into a function, then use `try` & `except` to get around the error. Unless I am misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I have a sequence where I am doing the counting. The sequence is like this "AAAACCCDEAAAAX " 
there is an "X" that I want to avoid counting. but with my code I am getting "KeyError: 'X' "

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to count the number of occurrences of this X character, you can use defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
counts = defaultdict(int)
```

counts will be an instance of a dictionary that instead of raising a KeyError, will return 0 if the key does not exist. This way you will be able to avoid the dictionary initialization altogether.

Update:
If you want to use if-else, I think it should be enough to do:

```
for char in line.strip(): 
    if char in keys:
        counts[char] += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. But I was thinking, if I want to use an if-else conditioning , how do I avoid this error?

Comment: I updated my answer. I haven't checked the code, but I think this should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly confused by your question. I guess the problematic line is

```
 aa_per = (counts[key]/total)*100
```

You can check for a `KeyError` by using a `try` block:

```
try:
    aa_per = (counts[key]/total)*100
except KeyError:
    aa_per = 0
```

I guess if the key doesn't occur the percentage should be 0 here.

In general `try` blocks are a powerful tool to check for exceptions or warnings. See also [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html